# How to do a parametric histogram?

Tags: plotting, graphics, manipulate, histograms, output

Is it possible to draw a spectral histogram from two random sets ?  More specifically, I have these two random functions (`fmin`, `fmax` and `Nwaves` would be variables in a Manipulate box) :

```
fmin = 0;
fmax = 4;

Amplitude[k_] := Amplitude[k] = If[k == 0, 1, RandomReal[{0.5, 1}]]
Frequency[k_, fmin_, fmax_] := Frequency[k, fmin, fmax] = If[k == 0, 1, RandomReal[{fmin, fmax}]]
```

where `k` is an integer variable going from `k = 0` up to `k = Nwaves`.  Lets take `Nwaves = 50`.  I would like to plot the *random frequencie*s on an horizontal axis, and their *random amplitude* on the vertical axis to define a *spectral plot*.

How can we do this plot in Mathematica ?  Please, note that I'm using Mathematica version 7.

**EDIT :**  This is almost a solution, but it's not exactly like an "histogram" (with thin vertical bars) :

```
Clear["Global`*"]

fmin = 0;
fmax = 4;

Amplitude[k_] := Amplitude[k] = If[k == 0, 1, RandomReal[{0.5, 1}]]
Frequency[k_, fmin_, fmax_] := Frequency[k, fmin, fmax] = If[k == 0, 1, RandomReal[{fmin, fmax}]]

ListPlot[
    Table[{Frequency[k, fmin, fmax], Amplitude[k]}, {k, 0, 50}],
    PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 1}},
    PlotStyle -> {Blue, AbsolutePointSize[10]},
    AspectRatio -> 1,
    Frame -> True,
    ImageSize -> 500
]
```

[image: spectre]

Comment: If you only have Mathematica 7, please mention this in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you would like to use `Histogram3D`

```
Manipulate[
 Histogram3D[
 Table[{Frequency[k, r, fmin, fmax], Amplitude[k, r]}, {k, 0, Nwaves - 1}]],
 {{Nwaves, 1, Style["Number of waves", 10]}, 1, 50, 1, ImageSize -> Large, 
 Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"}}, {{fmin, 0, 
 Style["Min frequency", 10]}, 0, fmax, 0.001, ImageSize -> Large, 
 Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"}}, {{fmax, 4, 
 Style["Max frequency", 10]}, 0, 4, 0.01, ImageSize -> Large, 
 Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"}}, Delimiter, 
 Button[Style["Randomize", Bold, Red, 12], {r = RandomReal[]}, 
 Appearance -> "Palette", ImageSize -> {100, 24}], 
ControlPlacement -> Bottom, FrameMargins -> None]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While not an histogram, this Manipulate is mostly fun !

```
Clear["Global`*"]

r = 1;

Amplitude[k_, r_] := Amplitude[k, r] = If[k == 0, 1, RandomReal[{0.5, 1}]]
Frequency[k_, r_, fmin_, fmax_] := Frequency[k, r, fmin, fmax] = If[k == 0, 1, RandomReal[{fmin, fmax}]]

Manipulate[
    ListPlot[
        Table[{Frequency[k, r, fmin, fmax], Amplitude[k, r]}, {k, 0, Nwaves - 1}],
        PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 1}},
        PlotStyle -> {Blue, AbsolutePointSize[7]},
        AspectRatio -> 1,
        Frame -> True,
        ImageSize -> 400
    ],
    {{Nwaves, 1, Style["Number of waves", 10]},
        1, 50, 1, ImageSize -> Large,
        Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"}},
    {{fmin, 0, Style["Min frequency", 10]},
        0, fmax, 0.001, ImageSize -> Large,
        Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"}},
    {{fmax, 4, Style["Max frequency", 10]},
        0, 4, 0.01, ImageSize -> Large,
        Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"}},
    Delimiter, 
    Button[
        Style["Randomize", Bold, Red, 12],
        {r = RandomReal[]}, Appearance -> "Palette",
        ImageSize -> {100, 24}
    ],
    ControlPlacement -> Bottom,
    FrameMargins -> None
]
```

[image: spectre manipulate]